# Decompile Asp.Net web site Project

Tags: asp.net, reflector

we have an application in production and the code is in Pre-Compiled form. And I could'nt reach any source code. I searched a few web site, they suggest Reflector so used Reflector to get code behind files. I reached cs files  and add them  by changing the asp.cs. But I do not reached aspx.degigner.cs files. And when I build my project Dll files do not compile. Their modify date seen old date. I make a mistake I know but I could not solve this problem. Have any ideas on this issue?

Comment: "Does not compile" *does not help*. What errors are you getting? I would not expect a separate `filename.aspx.designer.cs` file necessarily. Those are simply something Visual Studio uses to separate the code that it generates from user code. A decompiler would not know which goes where, because the user could have written exactly the same code in the `filename.aspx.cs` file, anyway.

Comment: When I right click the web site and "Build Web Site"  I dont get any error. But when I check the dll file date on bin /debug folder, It is not newer version.

Comment: What happens if you delete the existing dll before you re-compile?

Comment: It is not find codebehind files on the aspx files.Error is "Could not load type 'login'"

Answer (score 0):

You can easily recreate your designer files by right-clicking on your Web Application Project and choosing "Convert to web Application"

Comment: It is not a web application. It is web site

Comment: I assumed if you were looking for designer files, you were using a web application project. You won't need the designer files for the site as these are specific to web application projects.

Comment: Yes I created a new web application project an add all files to new web application project. Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can find the compiled binaries in the [ASP.NET Temporary Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx) location.

> %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files